# What is this cabinet part called?

Tags: cabinets, hardware, plastic

The face of my cabinets are supported by these pieces. The drawers (which are suspended on the front) were overloaded and the clips broke. What is this part called so I know what to search for? I've tried looking online but there is no part number and I don't know what to search for.

[image: front]
[image: back]

Update: here's a picture of a intact brackets installed, and how they relate to the front of the cabinet and the drawers. The front of the drawer rail is supported on the face of the cabinet. The face of the cabinet is attached to the side with a dozen or so of the clips in question.

[image]

Comment: What about making them?

Comment: I'd much rather buy them. Tight on time lately. If I can't find them, I'll have to figure out an alternative like making them or using L-brackets. Pretty sure half of the material is particle board, so I'm anxious about messing around.

Comment: custom made, find a sticker with name/model in the cabinets

Comment: you can fix that with superglue and baking soda or a PVA hardener, which amplifies the bond strength a lot. You could also drill out the positive cylinder back into the well, and replace the post with a hacksaw-chopped segment of a thick nail.

Comment: A picture of where unbroken pieces like this are still in use in your cabinet may help us identify it.

Comment: Also, please confirm that the face and drawers were involved with this part, but not shelves?

Comment: It looks somewhat like a table top clip, but I haven't a clue why that would be used to hold a face frame on a cabinet or how it would be used in conjunction with a drawer. This desperately needs a picture of the cabinet itself showing one or more of these in their intended location so we can figure out what its purpose is. Then advice can be given on how to replace it.

Comment: Also, I've taken out the "where can I buy it" portion because that is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I'll post some full pictures tonight. Thanks guys.

Comment: Updated with a new picture.

Comment: That does help - it proves that these are _not_ shelf supports (even though it very much looked like one). Could you get a better picture from the inside of the cabinet aimed toward the corner of the side/face frame showing us where the screw is and where the pin is? I'm thinking that maybe the screw goes into the face frame and the pin into the cabinet side. In that case, the plastic pin is acting in shear and it's not surprising that it broke.

Comment: Yes, the screw is going into the face frame and the pin is going into the particle board wall that has pre-drilled holes.

Comment: You could steal one from a bottom shelf that is seldom used.   It doesn't solve the problem but it moves it to a place where it isn't so bothersome.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a shelf pin.  Those are the brackets that were used to put the RTA (Ready To Assemble) cabinets together.  Many contractors won't use glue, but I did in my own assembly.

Comment: Yes to this one. The new picture shows these as RTA pieces. @JoshuaD, you might reach out to the cabinet manufacturer, or replace them with small L brackets.

Comment: Shelf pin with screw hole, or tabletop clip similarly designed, might still be usable as a substitute. Or might not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks rather similar to a [Häfele Cabinet connector, Uno I, with pre-mounted special screw](https://www.hafele.com/us/en/product/cabinet-connector-uno-i-with-pre-mounted-special-screw/P-00861392/):

[image]

(Image from https://www.hafele.com/INTERSHOP/static/WFS/Haefele-HAC-Site/-/Haefele/en_US/pim/images/huge/ppic-00605623.jpg.)

Answer (score 1):

Look for the metal version, called a Shelf Support or Shelf Pin.  There's a version that has a hole in it for attachment.  5 mm and 1/4" are the usual pin sizes.

I have these plastic parts in my cabinets at home.  They look like ultra-cheap attachment for the perimeter of the front face (the edges) to the sides of the box.

Honestly, you'd get a better attachment by switching to a small, two-hole angle bracket (corner brace).  The only drawback is you'd have to move it away from the peg hole and drill two new pilot holes for the screws, which are likely too close to the corner to fit a drill.  I suspect the cabinet face was pre-drilled before assembly.  If the front face is completely detached, I would suggest getting a set of small corner braces instead of the shelf pins, and adding some wood glue where the surfaces meet up.

Comment: It does seem like some sort of shelf support pin, however, the OP mentioned it in conjunction with the "face" of his cabinet and in relation to drawers. I think we need more clarity from the OP before we can have a chance of accurately answering...

Comment: @FreeMan I've expanded my answer for accuracy.

Comment: I'm inclined to go with a few l-brackets too. A little anxious about screwing into the particle board the walls are made of.

Comment: @JoshuaD your concerns are valid! There are specific screws designed for use in particle board - they have a very coarse thread. You will want to drill pilot holes and use appropriate length screws. I'd suggest hand driving the screws as it's easy to over torque and strip the "wood" out when using a powered driver.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us a photo of one still installed?

Shelf pin with provision for a fixing screw is my guess. You may not be able to match it, but you can get a set of four shelf pins for the same size hole (there are only a few common sizes) and replace the other as well. Probably with something much prettier and stronger; that one was designed to be cheap, not good.

Comment: Updated with requested picture. Thank you.